# Yii2 force JSON response regardless of content header

Tags: json, rest, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm trying to make Yii2 API that only returns JSON, so in the configuration I've setup the response component like this:

```
'response' => [
    'format' => yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON,
    'charset' => 'UTF-8',
]
```

However Yii2's `yii\filter\ContentNagotiator` still checks the client headers and if the client requests `application\xml`, it would serialize the response as XML. This however is unwanted behaviour for this API.

Is there a way to force only `JSON` response?

Answer (score 2):

Modify behaviors function in your controller:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();

    $behaviors['contentNegotiator']['formats']['text/html'] = Response::FORMAT_JSON;

    return $behaviors;
}
```

Guide in yii2 document: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-response-formatting.html

Good luck and have fun!